# Set Maximum Tables In A Database

Tags: mysql, table, limits

I need to set up a MySQL database with a maximum number of tables which can be created in it.

For example, if I have my maximum at 5 tables for a single database, and someone attempts to create a 6th table, an error will be raised.

Also note that this restriction can not affect other databases. For example, database 1 can have a max of 5 tables, and database 2 can have 10 tables, and database 3 can have unlimited tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!